# Does it make sense to have an annotated Abstract Controller class - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, abstract-class

Does it make sense to have an annotated (@Controller) **Abstract class** in Spring MVC driven container, basically would like to place most of the reusable methods such as **exception handlers** in the Abstract class and extend that with the base class, so that don't have to repeat the same boilerplate code. For example.

**Abstract Controller Class:**

```
    @Controller
    abstract class AbstractExternalController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseModel handleNotFoundException() {
            final ResponseModel response = new ErrorModel();
            response.setStatus("404");
                response.setMessage("Resource Not Found");
                return response;
             } 
...

    }
```

**Base Controller Class**

```
@Controller
class ExternalControllerXXX extends AbstractExternalController  {

...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is unnecessary to annotate your `AbstractExternalController` class with the `@Controller` anntation, although, leaving it there will not break anything.  Regardless of whether or not you have the `@Controller` annotation, you certainly can have the method annotations, and they will work.  Your `ExternalControllerXXX` extending it will be added to the application context (because it is annotated with a streotype annotation), and the `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseStatus` annotations will be honored.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Nicholas. You are absolutely right regarding not annotating the abstract class with @Controller, but doesn't hurt as it helps to see that the class is meant for Controller classes.